# How to create a serialized JSON object in c#

Tags: c#, json

Hi I want to create the following:

```
{
    "RetailerMappings": {
        "Title": "unwanted HR186320 Philips VivaCollection juicer HR1863/20",
        "ModelName": "HR186320 Philips VivaCollection juicer HR1863/20"
    },
    "ManufacturerId": 14,
    "RetailerId": 652,
    "SaveMapping": false
}
```

First if all I did the following:

```
//first get the mapping rules:
string jsonRetailerMappings = "";
jsonRetailerMappings = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
{
    mappingRule.ManufacturerMappingField,
    mappingRule.RetailerMappingField

});

string json = "";

//Create the JSON body request:
json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
{
    RetailerMappings =jsonRetailerMappings,
    ManufacturerId = manufacturer.Id,
    RetailerId = retailer.Id,
    SaveMapping = false
});
```

However this returns the following:

```
{
"RetailerMappings":"
{\"ManufacturerMappingField\":\"ModelName\",
\"RetailerMappingField\":\"Title\"}",
"ManufacturerId":114,
"RetailerId":2593,
"SaveMapping":false
}
```

So I'm not sure how to get:

```
"RetailerMappings": {
        "Title": "unwanted HR186320 Philips VivaCollection juicer HR1863/20",
        "ModelName": "HR186320 Philips VivaCollection juicer HR1863/20"
    },
```

As Title and ModelName depends on the mapping rules:

```
mappingRule.ManufacturerMappingField,
mappingRule.RetailerMappingField
```

and depending on the mapping rule I need to get values from:

```
foreach (var row in dataRows)
```

which is the outer loop..
so for example if
mappingRule.ManufacturerMappingField is Title I would use:

```
Title = row.Title,
```

I hope what I m asking makes sense.

Thanks

Edit:

```
  foreach (var row in dataRowsNamesUs)
            {
                try
                {                  

                        #region replaceWithAPIcall
                        //New Auto Mapper
                        Product autoMapped = null;
                        if (rpmn == null && manufacturerRetailer != null && manufacturerRetailer.UseAutoMapper)
                        {
                            var mappingRules = autoMapperRuleRepository.GetAutoMapperRulesByManufacturerRetailer(file.ManufacturerId, file.RetailerId).OrderBy(r => r.Ordering).ToList();

                            foreach (var mappingRule in mappingRules)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    //old --  autoMapped = autoMapper.GetMapping(row, possibleMatches, mappingRule);

                                    //new api request: (change this to proper url (config setting))
                                    var apiUrl = "http://localhost:49347/api/map";


                                    //first get the mapping rules:
                                    string jsonRetailerMappings = "";
                                    jsonRetailerMappings = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                                    {
                                        mappingRule.ManufacturerMappingField,
                                        mappingRule.RetailerMappingField

                                    });

                                    string json = "";

                                    //Create the JSON body request:
                                    json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                                    {
                                        RetailerMappings =jsonRetailerMappings,
                                        ManufacturerId = manufacturer.Id,
                                        RetailerId = retailer.Id,
                                        SaveMapping = false
                                    });

                                    string result = "";
                                    using (var client = new WebClient())
                                    {
                                        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                                        result = client.UploadString(apiUrl, "POST", json);
                                    }
                                    //this will need to be changed to automapped success..
                                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    Logger.Warn("Failed to auto map.", ex);
                                }
                                if (autoMapped != null)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        #endregion replaceWithAPIcall
...
```

and a model:

```
namespace Automapper.Core.Models
{
    public class MappingParameters
    {
        public Dictionary<RetailerProductMappingField, string> RetailerMappings { get; set; }
        public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
        public int RetailerId { get; set; }
        public bool SaveMapping { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Actually I think I'm overcomplicating things

The following should work:

```
   json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                                    {
                                        RetailerMappings = row,
                                        ManufacturerId = manufacturer.Id,
                                        RetailerId = retailer.Id,
                                        SaveMapping = false
                                    });
```

Comment: JSON.NET would be useful, I would project out your information using selects into anonymous objects

Comment: This isn't making too much sense. Please post a complete, minimal reproduce of your problem. We don't know what *outer loop* means in your code. Without enough information, we can't help.

Comment: Do you have a model backing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who had a look at this.

The solution that I found was as follows:

```
   json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                                    {
                                        RetailerMappings = row,
                                        ManufacturerId = manufacturer.Id,
                                        RetailerId = retailer.Id,
                                        SaveMapping = false
                                    });
```

this was because row contained everything that I needed.

However, if it didn't and I had to create the pairing from scratch the following also works (I have had to use it in a different are of the code)

```
  Dictionary<string, string> retailerMappingDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            retailerMappingDictionary.Add(vm.RetailerMappingField.ToString(), testString);

 json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                RetailerMappings = retailerMappingDictionary,
                ManufacturerId = vm.ManufacturerId,
                RetailerId = vm.RetailerId,
                SaveMapping = false
            });
```

Where vm.RetailerMappingField.ToString() is the retailermapping value I need to get I.e Title / ModelName /SKU

and teststring is the value which needs to go in the mapping field.

Answer (score 2):

With json.net you can just serialize the following, I assume JavaScriptSerializer should give similar results (if not, consider switching to json.net):

```
new 
{
    RetailerMappings = new
    {
       Title = "unwanted HR186320 Philips VivaCollection juicer HR1863/20",
       ModelName = "HR186320 Philips VivaCollection juicer HR1863/20"
    },
    ManufacturerId = 14,
    RetailerId =  652,
    SaveMapping = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Json.NET https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Modify your model to match the output you want.

```
class MappingParameters
{
    public RetailerMappings RetailerMappings { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    public int RetailerId { get; set; }
    public bool SaveMapping { get; set; }
}

class RetailerMappings
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
MappingParameters mapping = new MappingParameters();
mapping.RetailerMappings = new RetailerMappings();
mapping.RetailerMappings.Title = "unwanted HR186320 Philips VivaCollection juicer HR1863/20";
mapping.RetailerMappings.ModelName = "HR186320 Philips VivaCollection juicer HR1863/20";
mapping.ManufacturerId = 14;
mapping.RetailerId = 652;
mapping.SaveMapping = false;
```

---

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mapping);
```

---

```
{
    "RetailerMappings": {
       "Title": "unwanted HR186320 Philips VivaCollection juicer HR1863/20",
       "ModelName": "HR186320 Philips VivaCollection juicer HR1863/20"
    },
    "ManufacturerId": 14,
    "RetailerId": 652,
    "SaveMapping": false
}
```